# Latest OS X update causes Finder crash (SIGSEGV)

Tags: finder, kernel-panic, kernel

Does any one know how to fix an error like this?

```
Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)
Exception Codes: KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x0000000102e50cf2
```

My Finder keeps crashing after updating my Mac this morning. I've tried [TotalFinder](http://totalfinder.binaryage.com/) but this also crashed as if it was Finder.

Any ideas?

The tickets shows OS X 10.8.3… but my Terminal shows this:

```
jycr753:~ hakunamatata$ sw_vers -productVersion
10.8.5

jycr753:~ hakunamatata$ system_profiler SPSoftwareDataType
Software:

    System Software Overview:

      System Version: OS X 10.8.5 (12F45)
      Kernel Version: Darwin 12.5.0
      Boot Volume: hakunamatata
      Boot Mode: Normal
      Computer Name: jycr753
      User Name: jycr753 (hakunamatata)
      Secure Virtual Memory: Enabled
      Time since boot: 2:01
```

I've also tried looking at `kextstat` to make sure that I dont have any kernel extensions, and it all looks fine… 
[Log error](https://www.dropbox.com/s/goc1bsv405zhnao/error.rtf)

Comment: I would be helpful to see the full error log. but try this if you find the "External Modification Warnings:"
Thread creation by external task.
Are you using DropBox or a Finder extension like TotalFinder?
Remove them.

Comment: Im using Dropbox, I dont have TotalFinder or PathFinder either...

Comment: Do you have the following in the log "External Modification Warnings" "Thread creation by External task" ? Also you said you did use the TotalFinder ?

Comment: @Buscar웃 I have added a link to the log, but I do have that in the log, `External Modification Warnings:
Thread creation by external task.` And I dont use Totalfinder I just installed to see if it will work, but once I crashed I removed

Comment: Thank you. I downloaded your log and you do have the External Modification Warnings .... in it (at the top)

Comment: and this report and the bottom:                      External Modification Summary:
  Calls made by other processes targeting this process:
    task_for_pid: 20
    thread_create: 1
    thread_set_state: 0
  Calls made by this process:
    task_for_pid: 0
    thread_create: 0
    thread_set_state: 0
  Calls made by all processes on this machine:
    task_for_pid: 7888
    thread_create: 136
    thread_set_state: 0

Comment: @Buscar웃 I don't what it means... :(

Comment: Just try to remove the Dropbox (for now) and restart without it. Sorry I have to leave, be back in 2 hours, good luck!

Comment: @Buscar웃 thanks for the help mate, i really appreciated

Comment: @Buscar웃 Still the same, even totally removing DP... It is really annoying..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution for this was actually google drive, its kernel extension was creating conflicts with finder if the icon was showing in the status bar.